# "IF" with conditions across multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

I am looking for a formula to add to the column "Status" to do the following:

If Name = "A" and Project = "TT" and Number > 5, write "PASS" otherwise write "FAIL"

If Name = "A" and Project = "NN" and Number > 10, write "PASS" otherwise write "FAIL"

If Name = "B" and Project = "TT" and Number > 20, write "PASS" otherwise write "FAIL"

I struggle puting together something that works with "IF" and "OR".

Would anyone be able to offer a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this into parts:

- `AND(A2="A",B2="TT",C2>5)`
- `AND(A2="A",B2="NN",C2>10)`
- `AND(A2="B",B2="TT",C2>20)`

Then using `OR`:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2="A",B2="TT",C2>5),AND(A2="A",B2="NN",C2>10),AND(A2="B",B2="TT",C2>20)),"PASS","FAIL")
```

[image]